# Why am I getting an error when passing this 2D array to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays

When I try to pass the sales array to the function, I get this: error

> C2664: 'printArray' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [4][5]' to 'int'

Here's the array and call:

```
    int sales[4][5], row, column;

    for (row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < 5; column++)
        {
            cin >> sales[row][column];
        }
    }

printArray(sales);
```

and here's the function:

```
void printArray(int A[4][5])
{
  for(int R=0;R<4;R++)
  {
     for(int C=0;C<5;C++)
        cout<<setw(10)<<A[R][C];
     cout<<endl;
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Function prototype should be just printArray(int A[][5])

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function

Have a look at this

Comment: Make sure the prototype argument is the same on the function definition

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I removed the 4 and read those links. It looks right to me, but I still get the same conversion error. @mr5 Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user3053293 Make sure there are no overloaded function above(before the function `call`). Or try to compile this code first :

`void printArray(int arr[4][5]) { } 

int main() { int arr[4][5]; printArray(arr); }` 

before we proceed.

Comment: @user3053293 Also you should follow `Nipun Talukdar` answer, it is much preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
void printArray(int A[][5])
{
  for(int R=0;R<4;R++)
  {
     for(int C=0;C<5;C++)
        cout<<setw(10)<<A[R][C];
     cout<<endl;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

**EDIT:**
There are some other way to do it. Thought I share it to you:

You can pass a array of pointers.

```
void printArray(int *A[4])
```

You can pass a pointer to pointers.

```
void printArray(int **A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the printArray function to something like this:

```
void printArray(int *A, int row, int col)
{
  for(int R=0;R<row;R++)
  {
     for(int C=0;C<col;C++)
        cout<<A[R * col +  C] << endl;
   }
}
```

Then you call this function as shown:

```
  printArray(&sales[0][0], 5, 5);
```

Note you pass the row and column counts as value to the function

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error when using that code: error C2664: 'printArray' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int *' to 'int [][5]'

Comment: How are you calling the function ? You have to pass the address of sales[0][0]